# Does CachedURLResponse persists in between app launches?

Tags: ios, swift, caching

The example below from [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/accessing_cached_data), shows how manually create a `CachedURLResponse` for a `UrlSession`.

One of the parameters is `storagePolicy` (in the example set to `.allowedInMemoryOnly`).

If set such parameter to `.allowed` (instead of `.allowedInMemoryOnly`, the cache should be stored to hard disk. Does this mean that it persists in-between app launches?

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask,
                willCacheResponse proposedResponse: CachedURLResponse,
                completionHandler: @escaping (CachedURLResponse?) -> Void) {
    if proposedResponse.response.url?.scheme == "https" {
        let updatedResponse = CachedURLResponse(response: proposedResponse.response,
                                                data: proposedResponse.data,
                                                userInfo: proposedResponse.userInfo,
                                                storagePolicy: .allowedInMemoryOnly)
        completionHandler(updatedResponse)
    } else {
        completionHandler(proposedResponse)
    }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

> The URLCache class implements the caching of responses to URL load
>   requests, by mapping NSURLRequest objects to CachedURLResponse
>   objects. It provides a composite in-memory and **on-disk cache**, and lets
>   you manipulate the sizes of both the in-memory and on-disk portions.
>   You can also control the path where cache data is **persistently** stored.

- **case allowed** Storage in  URLCache  is allowed without restriction.
- **case allowedInMemoryOnly** Storage in  URLCache  is allowed; however
  storage should be restricted to memory only.

Yes.